# jQuery() vs jQuery.parseHtml() whitespace syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of javascript that is causing a syntax error in jQuery:

```
$(document).find('.Container').replaceWith($(data).find('.Content'));
```

The code itself if fairly innocuous all it does is takes the response data from an ajax call, targets some inner content and then substitutes this content for that of a container div element. However when the response data has leading space it causes a syntax error within jQuery.

For example the following stripped back reponse data is fine:

```
$("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>")
```

However the same response with a preceding space is not:

```
$(" <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>")
```

And gives the following error message:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I am guessing it may have something to do with the way that jQuery is testing the parameters of jQuery function (which $() is an alias for) to differentiate between the different overloads.

I also noticed that the jQuery function `$.parseHTML()` seems to cope with leading spaces as the following line of code is fine:

```
$.parseHTML(" <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>")
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug with jQuery? Or is it simply a case that the `jQuery()` function requires that it should not have leading spaces.

Btw the version of jQuery is 1.9.1

UPDATE ******************************************************************************************

Thanks to a tip off from a colleague I've found out that this is an actual bug (although it wasn't initially accepted as one by the jQuery team - [read the comments](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13223)). It looks like it will be/has been 'fixed' in jQuery 1.10/2.0.

Comment: This is not a bug. the `$()` function can take different things (selectors, elements, arrays, objects, functions and markup). It makes sense for it not to support leading whitespace in markup, because it uses the presence of a first `<` character to differentiate between selectors and markup.

Comment: When its rly only about the leading space, then `trim()` the content before passing it to the function: `$(" <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>").html().trim();`

Comment: Is there a difference between `'input'` and `' input'` in CSS selectors? That's about the only reason I can think of as to why they wouldn't just trim the string before doing the test to see if it is HTML.

Comment: @Fuzzyma How do you call functions on something that itself throws a syntax error? You need to be trimming **before** you pass to the jQuery function, not calling trim on the result of a function call after passing to it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist In fairness *everything* in jQuery starts with a selector. It makes sense to only do those iterations if it's absolutely necessary rather than assuming they're necessary first.

Comment: @Anthony Grist: Dangerous mistake of mine. Wanted to have an example and did it wrong. So again: `$(" <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>".trim());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with `<tag ... >`)

So it appears jQuery is looking for `<tag` at the start of your string and not finding it. Then falling back to try and parse this as a selector which is, of course, invalid

Comment: Yes that makes sense I thought that it might be due to they it was testing for the overloaded parameters.

Answer (score 6):

That's because when you use `$('<html>')`, jquery check the first and last character in the string.

[See the relevant code here.](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L134)

So when you input a space as first character, jQuery try the get an element in the DOM, not to parse the HTML.

Comment: Thank you - from the link you posted it is clear the code is indeed checking a '<' character at the start of the string parameter and using that to differentiate between html string and regex strings.