# find a specific html element in (html)string coming from server without appending it to the dom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I try to analyse a string that I fetch from server, to ensure the content is what I     expect.

My goal:

- load html from my ad-service backend
- ensure it is an ad and not for example some error page
- display the content in an iframe if the test was successfull

I already found stackoverflow answers (see in code below) but I fail.

My test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>Test ad</title></head>
    <body>
        <img id="promo_news" src="test-ad-pic0.png" alt="Test ad">
    </body>
</html>
```

My code to test the retrieved html:

```
function isLoadedHtmlAnAd(loadedHtmlCode) {

    // trim is necessary to get rid of a jquery error when checking the string 
    // in isLoadedHtmlAnAd(see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061815)
    loadedHtmlCode= loadedHtmlCode.trim(); 


    // inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403888
    let tempDom = $.parseHTML(loadedHtmlCode);
    let markerElement = $('#promo_news', tempDom);

    if(markerElement.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {

        // inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726480
        tempDom = $(loadedHtmlCode);
        let markerElement = tempDom.find('#promo_news');
        if(markerElement.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that the markerElement is not found.

I can see that the loaded html is the right one and includes the img tag with the id #promo_news

Any idea what I do wrong?
I'm also open to other ideas how to detect if the html is an ad.

Thanks!

The stackoverflow answers metioned in my code to click through

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403888
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726480

Comment: What exactly does the HTML fragment look like?

Comment: The full html is included above. Anyway, I found the problem. Thanks for trying to help!!

Answer (score 0):

I missed the solution in one of the linked answers.

I wrote

```
let tempDom = $.parseHTML(loadedHtmlCode);
let markerElement = $('#promo_news', tempDom);
```

This works

```
let tempDom = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(loadedHtmlCode));
let markerElement = $('#promo_news', tempDom);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403888